# Android How to calclulate the movement speed without the getSpeed()

Tags: android, performance, gps

As we all know GPS system is far from perfect and when you go around with your app using the gps when the GPS loses the signal and it starts calculating again. And if you try to calculate the distance correctly it will start calculating and for example if you were 30 meters away from your destination it will calculate for example 130 meters. Which messes my how calculation of the distance up. So I found some suggestion that I should filter the GPS coordination using the speed.

I want to calculate the speed without the `location.getSpeed()` I want to calculate the speed by comparing the distance from the last known coordinates to the coordinates at some given point and I get the speed of the device moving. And if the speed is for example greater than 15 m/h coordinates are invalid and don't re-calculate the distance.

Comment: Velocity is the first derivative of speed: `v = dx/dt`. Average velocity is the total change in distance over the total change in time. With two location, time data points, you can determine the velocity vector between those coordinates.

Comment: can you show me in code?

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as V = (Distance) / (Elapsed time).
So lets say you read your location1 at time X.
Than at some point after X lets say at time Y you read your location again. 
Than you'll have

```
float distance = location1.distanceTo(location2);
```

which is float in meters (see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)

To have your velocity as in meters per seconds if you calculate X - Y as

```
float X = System.currentTimeMillis(); //When you get the first location
float Y = System.currentTimeMillis(); //When you get the second location
//...
//Than when calculating
float timeElapsed= (Y - X)/1000; //In seconds
```

Than the velocity in meters per second will be

```
float V = distance/timeElapsed;
```

If you want to calculate average velocity, you need to store the velocities in a list lets say, and than calculate average from all those velocities calculated between each two points. So if you have location l1, l2, l3, l4 ..... ln, V1 will be velocity between l1 and l2, V2 will be between l2 and l3, and Vn-1 will be between ln-1 and ln. You will store all Vn in a list (for example) than you caluclate the average as

Vavg = (V1 + V2 + V3 ... + Vn)/n

**UPDATE:**
In your activity

```
Location previousLocation = null;
float previousTime = 0;
float velocity = 0;
```

Than:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
  boolean hasPrevious = true;
  if (previousLocation == null || previousTime == 0) {
      hasPrevious = false;
  }
  float currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  if (hasPrevious) {
     float timeElapsed = (currentTime - previousTime)/1000;
     velocity = loc.distanceTo(previousLocation)/timeElapsed;
  } 
  storeToPrevious(loc, currentTime);
}
```

In a different function

```
private void storeToPrevious(Location l, float time) {
   previousLocation = new Location(l);
   previousTime = time;
}
```

Comment: Ok this looks reasonable but I get my distance in the OnLocation() so if I put X and Y to take the Time. Wont they have the same values?

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis() returns the current time in milis. If you call it when you get the first location you will get one value, than 10 seconds later when you get a second location, you will have different value. They are written next to each other for example.
It doesnt matter really if you call them as written you will still get different values, since it returns milliseconds.

Comment: In the class you will have variables called previousTime = 0 and previousLocation = null. When in onLocation you will check if previousTime is zero and previousLocation is null. If so, just store the current location in previousLocation and System.currentTimeMillis() in previousTime. Next time you do the calculation as distance between previousLocation.distanceTo(location) and timeElapsed as System.currentTimeMillis - previousTime. After the calculation store the new values of location and time in the previousLocatin and previousTime variables.

Comment: Don't use System time. Each Location has an the "exact" time it was actually collected, not the time you processed it (which can differ slightly). So it will be much more accurate to use the time stamp attached to the location. You don't even need to store the time, you already have it. See my example above.

Answer (score 2):

This may do what you want. It is written in Kotlin. It applies a weighted moving average. Most recent locations have a heavier weight. It can "smooth" out the speed, at the cost of adding more lag. This was to get around a bug in certain situations that I could not use getSpeed(). But normally if you use "Fused" location on Android, the speed is quite stable and accurate on a typical modern, ACTIVE phone.

```
var recentGPSLocationSegments = listOf<Pair<android.location.Location, android.location.Location>>()

fun applyWeightedMovingAverageSpeed(location: android.location.Location, previous: android.location.Location): Double
{
    recentGPSLocationSegments += Pair(location, previous)
    val cachedLocationsNs = location.elapsedRealtimeNanos - 4500000000 // 4.5 seconds, This will typically get 4 entries (1 second apart)
    val targetZeroWeightNs = location.elapsedRealtimeNanos - 5000000000 // 5.0 seconds, Weights will be approx 5000000000, 4000000000, 3000000000, 1000000000

    // Toss old locations
    recentGPSLocationSegments = recentGPSLocationSegments.filter { it -> it.first.elapsedRealtimeNanos > cachedLocationsNs }

    // Total up all the weights. Weight is based on age, younger has higher weight
    val weights = recentGPSLocationSegments.map { it.first.elapsedRealtimeNanos - targetZeroWeightNs }.sum()

    // Apply the weights and get average speed in meters/second
    return recentGPSLocationSegments.map { speedFromGPS(it.first, it.second) * (it.first.elapsedRealtimeNanos - targetZeroWeightNs) }.sum() / weights
}

fun speedFromGPS(location: android.location.Location, previous: android.location.Location): Double
{
    val dist = location.distanceTo(previous)
    val time = (location.elapsedRealtimeNanos - previous.elapsedRealtimeNanos) / 1000000000.0
    return dist / time
}

val locationManagerExample: LocationListener = object : LocationListener
{
    var lastLocation: android.location.Location? = null
    var lastPreviousLocation: android.location.Location? = null

    override fun onLocationChanged(location: android.location.Location?)
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            if (lastPreviousLocation != null)
            {
                currentSpeed = applyWeightedMovingAverageSpeed(location, lastPreviousLocation!!)

                lastPreviousLocation = lastLocation
            }

            lastLocation = location

            if (currentSpeed < 0.0)
            {
                currentSpeed = 0.0
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle)
    {
    }

    override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String)
    {
    }

    override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use fused and get an accurate speed even when there is no GPS reception? how?