# Android LocationServices getLastLocation returns speed as 0

Tags: android, gps, location, location-client, location-services

It gets connected, I can get the latitude and the longitude of the coordinate, but when I do the following code, speed = 0, why can't it take the speed from the location?

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

    Log.i("","geof is s onLocationChanged ENTERED");
    if (LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mLocationClient) != null) {

         locEnd = location;
         Log.i("","geof is s speed of locend:" + location.getSpeed());
    }
}
```

This will always be my response:

```
03-31 17:43:57.227  31463-31463/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ geof is s speed of locend:0.0
```

And this are my permissions:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="nl.hgrams.passenger.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: why in the world are you using `getLastLocation` on your `onLocationChanged` you already have the location being given to you

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I also edited the code, will check now

Comment: @tyczj I also get 0.0 as speed, even if I directly take the location

Comment: It's pretty normal (and common) for a location object not to have a speed, a.k.a it'll return 0.0 in this case. Not sure why you need it for, but generally you should handle the 0.0 case appropriately.

Comment: Well I need to send to the server 0, if my location is stationary, the speed, if  is > 0, and if the location doest not have a speed, then I should send -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()

But it's "normal" for getSpeed to return 0.0 to you as a default because your location does not have speed (as showed in the documentation).

Comment: It's always 0. Even if I'm on the car. Hence the question

Comment: I'm just going to accept this answer, because I already fixed this.
I checked the hasSpeed() and it returned false, something was wrong with the phone that I was testing on that it wouldn't work as expected.

Comment: I understand it has been a year or so since you've asked the question, but I've been attempting this suggestion made by another person:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22010404/7246518

Who knows, might help someone else.